# How does isinstance work in python for subclasses?

Tags: python, oop, python-internals, isinstance

Playing around with `isinstance`, I would like to know how it works for a subclass check.

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass

print(isinstance(C(), C)) # True, I understand this fine
print(isinstance(C(), B)) # True, Ok, but how is this `True`?
print(isinstance(C(), A)) # True, this too?
```

[What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance) explains that `isinstance` does work for a subclass as seen in my second and third `print` statement. My question is not that, but, how does it work? When class `A` was defined it had no information but about the existence of class `B` or class `C`, likewise `B` had no information about `C`.

According to [How does isinstance work for List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133058/how-does-isinstance-work-for-list) `__instancecheck__` is called for `isinstance`, so if my class `A` was created before `B` and `C` how does this Python know that `C()` is indeed an instance of one of the subclass (`B`, subclass of `A`) or subclass of subclass of `A` (`C`, which is a subclass of `B` which itself is a subclass of `A`)?

Does something happen when I inherit a class in Python such that the base class knows that a child class exists? If that is the case can anyone let me know how this works?

PS : Do let me know if any clarification is needed. Many Thanks.

Comment: It gets more fun, as you haven't even considered the existence of `__subclasshook__` in this example :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C()` holds a reference to its type, `C`, and `C` has a tuple `C.__mro__` of all its ancestors (including itself). The default `type.__instancecheck__` looks through that tuple to see whether an object is an instance of a particular class.

If you follow the function calls down from [`type.__instancecheck__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L897), you eventually end up in [this loop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L1415-L1417):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (PyTuple_GET_ITEM(mro, i) == (PyObject *)b)
        return 1;
```

---

Classes in Python *do* also have information about their subclasses - the C-level `PyType_Ready` function [informs](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L5580-L5588) the base classes about a subclass while readying the subclass. However, searching the inheritance graph downward from the base class would produce pathologically slow behavior for cases where the second argument to `isinstance` has a lot of descendants.

Answer (score 0):

The base class doesn't need to know anything about it's inheritance by other classes.
When you call the `isinstance()` on `C()`, which is a subclass of B (which is a subclass of A) it creates the inheritance tree from C upwards (all the way to object which is the base class of every class).
It then "knows" that A and B are there.
The order in which you defined A,B,C doesn't have any meaning.