# Using endswith() function inside a case statement in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to do a ‘match case’ statement where the user enter a file name with extension and then I tell them what the type of the file is and I get this error when I use the ‘endswith()’ function inside my ‘case’ statement. Can anyone please explain to me what is happening here because I am new to python.
My code:

```
file = input("File name: ")
file = file.lower.strip()
match True:
    case file.endswith(".png"):
       print("it’s an image"):
```

The error:
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP8V4.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Use an `if` statement, not `match/case`. `match` is for structural pattern matching.

Comment: If your goal is to match different extensions, then rewrite as `match os.path.splitext(file)[1]` and then include `case ".png":` and etc...

Answer (score 2):

As @Barmar said, the `match` statement is for structural pattern matching. So, you have to use an `if` statement to achieve what you want. Modified code:

```
file = input("File name: ")
file = file.lower.strip()
if file.endswith(".png"):
   print("It’s an image")
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can match against arbitrary Boolean predicates using Python's structural pattern matching syntax.

**I do not recommend this.** This is just an academic novelty; *please* go and use Dinux's answer. It's the correct answer.

Okay, disclaimers out of the way, Python doesn't give us a ton of room to work with here, compared to some languages. In Ruby, pattern matching against an arbitrary object simply invokes a method named `===`, which we can do whatever we like with (including, but not limited to, calling a method on the invocant). In fact, Ruby's `Proc` method has this built in, so in Ruby, we can write

```
case file
when proc { |x| x.endswith('.png') }
  ...
end
```

And it all just works. Scala, similarly, allows us to simply invoke a method of our own design (called [`unapply`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html)), and that method can do whatever we like.

Python's structural pattern matching is a bit more limited (and, as per my disclaimer above, that's honestly probably a good thing), but as with so many things in Python, we can always do what we want with a little creativity. The place that gives us the most control is [class patterns](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#class-patterns). When a class name appears in a pattern, followed by parentheses, Python is going to look to that custom class to figure out how to do the match.

> If `name_or_attr` is not an instance of the builtin `type`, `TypeError` is raised.
>
> A class pattern fails if the subject is not an instance of `name_or_attr`. This is tested using `isinstance()`.
>
> - If no arguments are present, the pattern succeeds if the `isinstance()` check succeeds. Otherwise:
> - If only keyword patterns are present, they are processed as follows, one by one:
>
>   - The keyword is looked up as an attribute on the subject.
>
>     - If this raises an exception other than `AttributeError`, the exception bubbles up.
>     - If this raises `AttributeError` the class pattern fails.
>     - Otherwise, the subpattern associated with the keyword is matched against the attribute value. If this fails, the class pattern fails. If it succeeds, the match proceeds to the next keyword.
>   - If all keyword patterns succeed, the class pattern as a whole succeeds.
> - If any positional patterns are present, they are converted to keyword patterns (see below) and treated as additional keyword patterns, preceding the syntactic keyword patterns (if any).

The bit at the bottom about positional arguments isn't relevant to our little misadventure here today. The part about keyword arguments initially looks promising. After all, attributes are looked up using `getattr`, which respects descriptors like `@property`, so we have control over the *lookup* part, but at that point we don't have access to the subject of our match (the thing to the right of the `match` keyword). All we can do is delegate to some *other* structural pattern matching technique, not write our own.

But we do have one thing that gives us total control here, and that's `isinstance`. `isinstance(obj, some_class)`, in Python, checks whether `obj` is an instance of `some_class`, either directly or by being an instance of a subclass. But that's not entirely true. `isinstance` also [magically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133058/how-does-isinstance-work-for-list) works on the abstract base classes in `collections.abc`. For instance, [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable) treats any object that has an `__iter__` method as an instance of itself, regardless of whether or not the defining class actually subclassed `Iterable`.

This works because `isinstance` invokes a magic method called [`__instancecheck__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#class.__instancecheck__). This is *intended* to allow a sort of duck typing that agrees with `isinstance`, such as in `collections.abc` or the `typing` module. But it can also be abused to give us arbitrary pattern matching power.

```
class BooleanCheck(type):

    def __new__(cls, predicate):
        return type.__new__(cls, "BooleanCheck", (object,), {
            "predicate": predicate,
        })

    def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
        return self.predicate(instance)
```

And here's the magic. `BooleanCheck` is a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) which we'll construct using a `lambda` as the `predicate` argument. `__new__` calls `type`'s `__new__` and defines the new "class" as a subclass of `object` with one field on its `__dict__`. Then we write an `__instancecheck__` which calls out to that predicate.

Now we can define a new "instance" of our "metaclass" (at this point I have to put airquotes around basically every word; this is *not* good Python coding practice)

```
my_pred = BooleanCheck(lambda x: x.endswith('.png'))
```

And then we can use `my_pred` as a structural pattern

```
filename = input("File name: ")
filename = filename.lower().strip()
match filename:
    case my_pred():
        print("Good; file name ends in .png")
    case _:
        print("Bad; try again")
```

And that's the story of why they took away my Python license.